# Android Gradle flavor to have less language support than Main

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to have 3 product flavors, and one of them will have less language support than Main. 
For example, only support /values-fr. 
Is there a filter function in Gradle? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566270/force-locale-for-android-flavor-with-resconfig

Answer (score 6):

From [Android Gradle Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), since version 0.7.0:

> - New option on product Flavor (and defaultConfig) allow filtering of resources through the -c option of aapt
>
>   - You can pass single value (resConfig) or multiple values (resConfigs) through the DSL.
>   - All values from the default config and flavors get combined and passed to aapt.
>   - See "basic" sample.

In the "basic" sample:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfig "en"
    resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi"
}
```

So, try the following to achieve what you asked for:

```
productFlavors {
    ...
    frOnly {
        resConfig "fr"
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that you might also want to include *dpi, port, land, etc.. as well

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, as expected. See this question to more information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566270/force-locale-for-android-flavor-with-resconfig