# Force locale for Android flavor with resConfig

Tags: android, gradle, localization, locale, android-productflavors

I am trying to use the resConfig and resConfigs from the Android Build system.

- Android Studio version 1.2.2
- Gradle build version 1.2.3
- OSX 10.10.3

I was having problem with these 2 options with my project so I started a new blank project with android studio. I attached my build.gradle where I only added resConfigs "en", "fr" under

```
android { 
   defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr" 
        ...
   }
}
```

And defined 2 basic flavors

```
productFlavors {
        fr {
            resConfig "fr"
        }

        en {
            resConfig "en"
        }
}
```

I then created a 2 strings.xml files and translated the hello_world default label

> /src/main/res/values/strings.xml (default) 
>   /src/main/res/values-en/strings.xml 
>   /src/main/res/values-fr/strings.xml

With this, I would expect to see only 3 values folders in MyApplication/app/builds/intermediates/res/en/debug since I defined in the resConfigs to only use "en" and "fr" and filter anything else

> /values/ 
>   /values-en/ 
>   /values-fr/

Although, all languages values folder are still in there so the resConfigs is not filtering anything apparently.

I would also expect to see the label hello_world from values-en when running enDebug flavor variant since I specified that the flavor en would use resConfig "en" although when I run the test app I see the label from /values-fr/strings.xml instead of /values-en/strings.xml since the language on the tablet is configured as French Canada

Am I misunderstanding the purpose behind resConfig? If so, how am I supposed to force a flavor to only run in only language and not be dependant on the OS locale setting? This solution must be compatible with flavorDimensions too since I use them in the real app I'm trying to configure.

**NOTE**: I also filed a bug since I think there really is a problem with this resConfig behavior https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180694

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, after many hours, here's the solution to my problem for those ending up with the same problem.

Turns out that resConfig is not for what I though. The proper and only way I found to force the locale for a specific flavor is like this:

First, make sure all your activities extends a common activity which will be responsible to force the locale. (*I had to create 2 since I have some activities extending FragmentActivity and some extending Activity. I also don't really like doing so in the Activities constructor but since I have to call applyOverrideConfiguration before any call is done on getResources, I need to call it before the activity's onStart*).

```
public class LocaleMainActivity extends Activity {

    public LocaleMainActivity() {
        ActivityUtils.forceLocale(this);
    }
}

public class LocaleMainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public LocaleMainFragmentActivity() {
        ActivityUtils.forceLocale(this);
    }
}

//Method from ActivityUtils
public static void forceLocale(ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    Locale defaultLocale = new Locale(BuildConfig.LOCALE);
    configuration.locale = defaultLocale;
    contextThemeWrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);      
}
```

Next, you need to define the locale in your build.gradle flavors

```
productFlavors {

    myFrenchFlavor {
     buildConfigField "String", "LOCALE", "\"fr\""
    }
    myEnglishFlavor {
      buildConfigField "String", "LOCALE", "\"en\""
    }
}
```

I tested the solution on API 19+. Works when you change language while in the app too.

**Alternate solution** (*won't work on Android M+ [see android bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=2070)*)
This solution is wide spreaded on stackOverflow but I faced a wall while implementing this on Android M so keep this in mind.

In the onCreate() of your AndroidApplication you can call updateConfiguration with the locale set.

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale(BuildConfig.LOCALE);
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

You will also need to reset it if you defined onConfigurationChanged()

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);            
        Configuration config = new Configuration(newConfig);
        config.locale = new Locale(BuildConfig.LOCALE);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

**EDIT:** Be aware that this applyOverrideConfiguration currently has a side effect which is explained here [Chromium webview does not seems to work with Android applyOverrideConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050784/chromium-webview-does-not-seems-to-work-with-android-applyoverrideconfiguration). The Chromium team are currently working on it!

Thanks.

Comment: as an aside (since i am the one who filed the bug report you linked above), the alternate solution mentioned above does work on M if the `context` used is from an `Activity` and not from an `Application`.

Comment: Tried this solution for devices >= API level 17, works. Only problem I am concerned is setting values in the constructor of `Activity` which is like an anti-pattern for Android component initialization. Did you ever encounter any issue using this approach i.e. crash or bug ?

Answer (score 6):

`resConfig` does not override the specified `resConfigs` of the `defaultConfig`, but just combines them instead. Thus you'll end up with all flavors containing `en` *and* `fr` resources.

So, to avoid that, you shouldn't specify any `resConfigs` in the `defaultConfig` and just set it in the specific flavor.

Further, the app will always include the default `values`, which means if you have English strings there, the `fr` flavor will still show up with English content on a device set to any non-French locale.